# Do we have to say "une monster" or "un monster" while talking about the energy drink?

Tags: genre, noms, noms-propres

I am searching for the grammatical gender of the brand "Monster Energy" when we are talking in French.

Is it "un monster" or "une monster"?

Answer (score 2):

It is "un monster".

I think you can guess by according it to the drink name. Like un soda, un thé, un café, une bière etc.

Comment: Beers are a notable exception.

Comment: C'est à cause du soda qu'on dit « un Perrier » ? Merci.

Comment: Eau, liqueur, tisane, vodka, tequila, absinthe, limonade... Autant de mots féminins pour des boissons. Il n'y a pas que "bière".

Comment: @Amphiteóth aucune idee. Peut-etre qu'il n'y a pas de regle apres tout. Je pense que ca doit aussi beaucoup changer en fonction de la culture locale. Il doit y avoir beaucoup de differences par exemple entre la France metropolitaine et le Quebec.

Comment: I would agree with above, as it's "un monstre", so "un monster" too...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi La question ne concerne pas les noms de boissons mais les noms de marques de boissons (brands) utilisés substantivement.  Je ne vois pas de marque de limonade, absinthe, liqueur ou tisane qui pourrait être utilisée de cette façon. On dit bien en revanche « une Heineken » ou « une Leffe ». Les marques d'eau sont généralement féminines: « une Évian, une Badoit » mais curieusement « un Perrier ». J'ai entendu aussi bien « un » que « une San Pellegrino » mais « une San Pé ».

Comment: @jlliagre Je pense que ça marche aussi pour la vodka et la tequila, mais c'est vrai que j'ai peut-être exagéré avec "liqueur" et "limonade". ("Perrier" sonne un peu masculin (par rapport à "Perrière"), ça doit expliquer le masculin)

Comment: @jlliagre Mais on dit « un Orval, des Orvaux ».

Comment: @Édouard Je viens de le découvrir. Une exception cependant très localisée d'après wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

Using the generic underlying word to figure out the gender is a sound practice [indeed](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13511/3177). But, I see this as a "boisson [*énergisante*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26505074)" or "[*énergétique*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=energy%20drink&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search)", depending; more so (to me) than a [*soda*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soda)(m., see [also](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870732)). The word "[boisson](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/boisson)" is *feminine*. The specific answer to the question is neither: a capital "M" is still [required](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1275) as this is no common name but rather a brand name. Despite there being *ten times* more web hits using the masculine (3000 hits with "boire un monster"), I would nevertheless suggest:

> Une (boisson énergisante de la marque) [Monster](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boisson_%C3%A9nergisante).