# Pourquoi dit-on « un Perrier » — le genre de la marque ?

Tags: usage, articles, genre, alimentation

Dans une [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13508) on a exploré le genre d'une *marque* de boisson énergisante; et en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/do-we-have-to-say-une-monster-or-un-monster-while-talking-about-the-energy-d/13511#comment25558_13511) on a aussi parlé des *eaux minérales/gazeuses* et on remarque qu'on dit « un Perrier ».<sup>1</sup>

Sommairement, c'est en 1906 qu'on donne le nom [*Perrier*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perrier_%28eau_min%C3%A9rale%29) à la source en question (*La compagnie de la Source Perrier*). En 1870 on a le premier slogan : « *La princesse des eaux de table* » (*Wikipedia*); on peut en lire bien d'[autres](http://www.lesartsdecoratifs.fr/francais/musees/musee-des-arts-decoratifs/collections/dossiers-thematiques/publicite/marques-et-personnages/perrier) - voir 1946, variations sur 1870 « *le champagne des eaux de table* »; 1949 : « L’eau Perrier minérale, gazeuse naturelle,... ». Puis en 1994, pour la première fois si directement dans un tel contexte : « *Et si l’homme se contentait de la violence d’un Perrier ?* ». Mais sommes toutes bien des références à l'eau, à ses propriétés, et bien des mots au féminin. Et sur le [site](http://www.perrier.com/fr/decouvrirperrier.html) de l'embouteilleur, on parle de l'eau minérale et du gisement de l'eau *Perrier* : on ne mentionne pas « un Perrier ». Il y a ici sans doute une forme de gestion du sens de la marque de commerce.

On pourrait penser que ces détails ont pu avoir un impact sur l'emploi du genre de manière contemporaine. On peut fouiller dans les emplois au corpus *Google* ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_DET%20Perrier%2Cun%20Perrier%2CPerrier%20Jouet%2Cperri%C3%A8re%2Cperreyer%2Ceau%20de%20Selz%2Ceau%20de%20source%2Ceau%20min%C3%A9rale%2Ceau%20gazeuse%2Ceau%20p%C3%A9tillante%2Csoda&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C*_DET%20Perrier%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ble_DET%20Perrier%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLe_DET%20Perrier%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmademoiselle_DET%20Perrier%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bles_DET%20Perrier%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun_DET%20Perrier%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bson_DET%20Perrier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20Perrier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPerrier%20Jouet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperri%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperreyer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceau%20de%20Selz%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceau%20de%20source%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceau%20min%C3%A9rale%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceau%20gazeuse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceau%20p%C3%A9tillante%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoda%3B%2Cc0)). Par ailleurs, l'entrée la plus ancienne (que j'ai trouvée) est celle de 1935 de Madame Simonne Wiccaert avec « [L'Afrique à vol d'oiseau: reportage aérien en Afrique septentrionale et centrale](http://books.google.com/books?id=lrMbAAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Perrier) »:

> « *Boy, un Perrier glacé !* » — *Un Perrier c'est l'eau minérale qu'on boit partout là-bas.*

Certains extraits peuvent aussi être [trompeurs](https://books.google.com/books?id=rRA7AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA48&dq=%22un%20perrier%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4yQkVfKJIZexyATO5YGABQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22un%20perrier%22&f=false). Mais donc, ce ne saurait être dû à l'impact d'une stratégie de réclame contemporaine en France ou sur le web. Dans un autre ordre d'idées on aura noté que *Perrier* c'est un patronyme usuel en France (et *La Perrière*, un toponyme); aussi que le nom commun existait (*perrier*, m, l'*ouvrier* à la carrière, l'*engin de siège* (une forme de [trébuchet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9buchet)) etc.; aussi *pierrière*).

**Question.** Pourquoi dit-on, sans doute dès l'origine, « un Perrier »; et quel serait le générique sous-jacent ?<sup>2</sup> A-t-on des exemples d'emploi avant 1935 ? Y a-t-il une règle ou un usage pour le « genre des marques » (dans le domaine de l'agroalimentaire/restauration); est-ce l'exception qui confirme une « règle » plus générale ?

---

<sub>**1**. L'idée d'utiliser le *générique sous-jacent* (eau, vin, champagne, boisson, soda, camion) pour déterminer le genre, c'est utile mais ça peut nécessiter l'apprentissage de [détails](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4078). Mais pas dans le cas qui nous occupe (et assurément je suis le seul à avoir pensé qu'on aurait pu qualifier une eau Perrier de « *soda* ») : c'est une *eau minérale*.</sub>
<sub>**2**. Est-ce à cause de l'importance des marques associées aux appellations d'origine, dont les génériques sont: vins, champagnes, dont *Perrier-Jouët*, fromages (j'ai noté avec amusement dans *Le Bon Usage* (Grevisse, Goosse, *ed. De Boeck Duculot*) à 99.a.4 - « *Fromage de Doubs, voisin du Munster* (Rob., s.v. mont-d'or) »). Est-ce suite au genre d'un nom commun antérieur (*perrier*, m) ? Par opposition à des noms/toponymes comme *La Perrière* avec sa particule par exemple ? Ou pour personnifier le fondateur *Monsieur Perrier* ?</sub>

Comment: Mon hypothèse est que la raison est morphologique.  _Perrier_ avec sa terminaison en _-ier_ est morphologiquement masculin, tout comme les noms en _-ière_ sont féminins.  Il y a parfois des exceptions, mais dans ces cas, l'usage tend au moins à hésiter, parfois réimpose le genre morphologique.

Comment: C'est vrai que je me suis toujours demandé aussi. On peut dire un Coca, un Perrier, un Sprite, un Ice Tea, un 7Up, mais une Roxana, une Cristalline, une Hépar, une Carola...
J'aime beaucoup la question, je vais suivre ça de près !

Comment: « une [coca](https://books.google.com/books?id=9IsIAQAAIAAJ&dq=étiemble+parlez-vous&q=coca&redir_esc=y) » fut, mais a perdu...

Comment: @PaulPicard Pour "*une*", vous citez des noms féminins ou hors gendre comme Hépar, bouteilles qui sont surtout connues comme eau minérale dans les rayons des grandes surfaces, et non par le biais des limonadiers.

Comment: Ah, j'avais pas vu ça comme ça. +1, Merci de l'explication ! :)

Comment: As is often the case, I've got nothing of substance to contribute to your good question, but the image of the “violence” of Perrier in the 1994 quote reminds me of a “warning” sign I saw in a bar in Normandy (Arromanches) long ago: “Attention: L’eau bue [l'obus] éclate! Buvez donc du calva!”  [‘responsibly’, bien entendu, comme avec de la (du?) Duff!]

Comment: @PapaPoule Thanks. Indeed what about _l'eau-de-vie_!! Words ending with an "a", except for names of dances i.e. samba, attract the masculin form. On the other hand, when it's the name of a place, the gender will be arbitrary. But beer lolll I can never construe that otherwise than feminine - une _Duff!_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Au restaurant je demande :

- "un Perrier" pour obtenir un flacon qui remplit un [verre] de Perrier pour étancher ma soif, il est habituellement servi dans une petite bouteille accompagnée d'*un verre* dans lequel il y a une rondelle de citron et des glaçons.
- "une bouteille de Perrier", et l'on m'apporte une bouteille de 75 cl que je peux partager, comme toute autre eau minérale gazeuse.

*Perrier* est un phonème masculin, qui est féminisé en "-ière", il n'est donc pas possible de demander "Garçon une Perrier" sans ajouter *bouteille* ; en revanche on sous-entend *verre* lorsqu'on utilise le masculin.

Si le Perrier se vendait en *chope*, peut-être y aurait-il "une Perrier" pour désigner un contenu plus grand qu'un verre, mais ce n'est pas l'usage.

Remplacez Perrier par un nom épicène comme Camille, Dominique ... et vous n'aurez aucune difficulté à dire "Garçon, une Dominique", même si cette boisson est servie de manière identique dans un flacon accompagnée d'un verre.

Comment: @Amphiteóth Dans un café, *un Perrier* servit en flacon ou en canette  laisse le mot Perrier masculin, et utilise un verre. En revanche *une Perrier* en montrant du doigt une cannette que l'on va boire directement (ou avec un chalumeau), en marchant (ou en discutant entre copains)... pourquoi pas : le geste déplace l'accent du contenu sur le contenant (*ou* la contenante ??), qui lui (*pourquoi pas* elle ??) est féminin(e ??).

Comment: On ironise un peu sur mon glissement avec le genre je crois :) Il n'y a aucune moquerie dans mon propos. Le genre de la marque c'est un peu elliptique. Une fois que j'ai compris ce qu'on explique je me questionne sur comment relier ça aux autres eaux et boissons diverses, puis aux autres objets. Aborder ça sous l'angle du générique sous-jacent c'est p-ê pas utile dans tous les cas quand il y a un usage répandu appuyé par la morphologie. La géométrie du générique varie. Peut-être qu'on ne peut généraliser. Merci!

Comment: @Amphiteóth Ni moquerie non plus dans mes réponses ! Seulement s'amuser des mots que le bon sens du commun des mortels assemble selon son bon vouloir, au grand dam des... tondeurs d’œufs ??...  :)

Comment: Merci, j'avais jamais entendu la chanson de Perret ! :) Quel refrain !

Comment: @ cl-r pourtant on dit une bière, même si elle servie dans un verre, ou même un demi alors que c'est une demi chope,  ou un café , même si c'est servi dans une tasse. Le sous-entendu verre n'a pas l'air pertinent.

Comment: @JoBedard bière est féminin, café masculin, on fait référence à la boisson et non à la marque de son vendeur. On dit parfois "une *eau* Perrier" pour signifier une eau minérale particulière. Quand *au demi* il correspond d'abord à un volume de 25 cl qui peut être aussi une demie 'fillette' (50 cl pour du rouge qui tache, bouteille à fond épais que les pochetrons tapaient sur le comptoir pour en appeler une autre), à chaque règle son exception ! il n'y a que les lois qui n'en ont pas (sauf peut-être aux limites de leur domaine)

Comment: et on dit une "kro" ou une "Leffe" pour faire référence à la bière plutôt qu'au contenant...le fait que pour Perrier on aurait choisi la référence au verre plutôt qu'au type de boisson (eau) me semble non pertinent. C'est une explication, mais ce n'est pas une règle. L'étymologie du  genre de Perrier  est, à mon avis, juste accidentel.

Comment: @JoBedard une "kro", une "Leffe" comme on dirait "une bière" ...puisque ce sont des bières ; la référence 'de base' est la sonorité masculine de Perrier à laquelle s'ajoute une incidente qui accentue : le verre, qui n'est pas à l'origine du choix masculin mais dont l'usage est sous-entendu.

Comment: @JoBedard Ce serait bien d'avoir plus d'une réponse, alors ne pas hésiter. Merci!

Comment: @Amphiteóth je n'ai pas de référence pour ça, juste des souvenirs de cours de linguistique.

Answer (score 3):

Moi, je dirais que le soda étant au masculin, les marques de soda aussi.
L'eau étant au féminin donnera une Evian, une Hépar....

Comment: La réponse est intéressante, mais bien que Perrier appartienne à Coca-Cola, cela ne demeure qu'une eau minérale gazéifiée. Pourquoi dans ce cas la traiter comme un soda ?

Comment: @RiguefortUltraquaillette Au temps pour moi, j'étais persuadé que c'était la Coca-Cola Company. Bien que la base de la réponse paraisse logique, je trouve simplement qu'il manque quelque chose pour que la réflexion soit poussée à son terme.

Answer (score 3):

La question ne pose pas vraiment de problème: Il s'agit d'une simple antonomase, et cette figure est d'un emploi très courant, Perrier n'étant pas du tout une exception: On dit aussi bien ***un Coca, un Vittel, un Ricard***, mais aussi ***une Peugeot, une Toyota, une Chrysler*** etc...

Suite à la juste remarque de "nonobstant", je complète au sujet du genre:
Il semble que cette question vient de ce que dans l'antonomase du nom propre pris comme nom commun ("un Perrier") on sous-entend toujours un substantif générique qui induit cette translation:  Dans le cas de Perrier, Ricard, Coca..., le mot sous-entendu est `un verre de...`, d'où le masculin, tandis que dans le cas de Peugeot, Toyota... on sous-entend `une voiture de marque...`, d'où le féminin.

C'est donc le genre du générique sous-entendu qui détermine celui qu'on applique à la marque utilisée comme nom commun.

Comment: Merci mais pouvez-vous préciser en quoi dire que c'est une [antonomase](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonomase) règle la question du genre employé ? Si vous étayez l"antonomase avec les exemples que vous proposez, que vous permettent-ils de dire au sujet du _Perrier_ ; qu'est-ce qui conditionne l'un ou l'autre genre lors de la lexicalisation, y a-t-il un souci de cohérence, un prototype, ou dites-vous que c'est aléatoire ?