# How common is using "chalumeau" for drinking straw in France?

Tags: vocabulaire, alimentation

For some reason everyone in Egypt is using "chalumeau" for drinking straw.
Is it commonly used in France? Can I use it anywhere in France? If not what is the widely used word?

Comment: I think it would improve the question if you explained why you think this (seemingly unrelated) word can be used like this.

Comment: Because for some reason everyone in Egypt is using it :) That's why I'm trying to understand what's right and what's wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Never heard or used *chalumeau* for ***paille***, only for a gas torch.

In Egyptian Arabic, the word [شـَليموه](http://eu.lisaanmasry.com/online/word.php?ui=en&id=8751) (shaleemooh) is indeed used for straw and likely originates from an older French usage which has disappeared now.

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chalumeau):

> B.− *P. anal*. Tuyau de paille, de matière plastique, parfois de verre ou de métal, utilisé pour aspirer un liquide, pour diriger le souffle vers l'extérieur. *Boire avec un chalumeau*; faire des bulles de savon avec un chalumeau :
>
> - 3. ... sa récréation favorite était de faire des bulles de savon. Assis devant sa porte, muni d'un **chalumeau**, il soufflait avec une adresse de jeune fille les sphères parfaites et fragiles. Maurois, Ariel ou la Vie de Shelley, 1923, p. 121.

Interestingly, all slavic languages use a word that sound similar to name a straw, e.g соло́ма (solóma) in Russian and сла́ма (sláma) in Bulgarian, which happen to [share the same Indo Europeans roots](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/solma) than the Greek *κᾰ́λᾰμος* (kálamos), the Latin *calamus* and *culmus* which gave the French *chalumeau* and *chaume* (thatch). The same Indo-European root is shared by the English *[haulm](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haulm)* and the German *[halm](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Halm#German)*.

Comment: Jamais entendu moi non plus, mais le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chalumeau) le mentionne néanmoins, avec exemple...

Comment: @Montéedelait Oui, bien sûr. Je l'ai vu aussi. La question concerne l'usage actuel.  Les exemples datent. Sur le web, on trouve *paille chalumeau*.

Comment: Naviguant de vieilles questions ce matin, j'ai trouvé [là](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13533/13100), dans le premier commentaire sous la réponse, un usage de chalumeau pour paille. Il semble bien que ça existe encore un peu...

Answer (score 3):

Non, pas en français de France. Mais peut-être chez nos cousins canadiens où un chalumeau est aussi un instrument servant à extraire l'eau d'érable à sucre (sic): https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalumeau_(ac%C3%A9riculture).
De là à utiliser ce terme pour désigner une paille, il n'y a qu'un pas.

Comment: Je ne connais pas cet emploi ; le chalumeau en acériculture n'est pas un terme d'emploi courant dans ma vie de tous les jours. Par ailleurs, le mot _instrument_ est ambigu ici à mon avis pour le non-initié, car c'est essentiellement le bec inséré dans l'entaille dont il s'agit, d'ailleurs votre article dit « pièce ». Merci !

Comment: Je confirme, si j'entendais cette expression pour une paille, je me demanderais d'où ça sort!

Comment: @Circeus 'Est bonne, pour l'arbre ça sort pluton de mars à avril !

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Chalumeau) knows the expression *Chalumeau à cocktail* to designate a large straw used to drink some cocktails but has no article on the topic.

I am French and I never heard this term. So I guess this is a technical term used in the cocktail industry but is not commonly used by the general population. Most people will just call it *une paille*.

Answer (score 2):

En Égypte, on a toujours utilisé le mot *chalumeau* pour boire un liquide. On a pris ça des Français de France. Mais depuis que je vis au Québec, j'ai dû changer pour le mot paille.

Voici ce que j'ai trouvé sur le net :

> Une paille, ou chalumeau, est un tube léger, généralement fait en plastique, dont on se sert pour aspirer, et le plus souvent boire, un liquide. Quelques modèles sont fabriqués en bambou en Asie, pour contrer l’utilisation extensive de plastique.

Comment: Bonjour ! Où sur le _net_ ?