# Bar Le France : grammaire

Tags: grammaire

Je suis actuellement en France où j’ai vu un bar qui s’appelle « Bar Le France ». Je cherche une explication grammaticale. Est-ce que ça veut dire « Le bar « la France » » ou est-ce autre chose ?

(Je pense aussi à « un/une (café) noisette » : là j’ai l’impression que la plupart des gens disent « une noisette », mais il y en a qui disent « un noisette »).

Comment: Peut-être un rapport avec le célèbre paquebot des années 60 ? https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/France_(paquebot)

Comment: Vous trouverez, je crois, une explication dans cette question https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13532/pourquoi-dit-on-un-perrier-le-genre-de-la-marque

Comment: Question semblable qui a déjà une excellente réponse acceptée. https://french.stackexchange.com/q/19159/358

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I**

Les mots utilisés pour nommer autre chose que ce qu'ils nomment originellement prennent très souvent le genre de la chose nommée ; un paquebot que l'on a arrêté d'utiliser il y a longtemps s'appelait « Le France »; si on utilisait le nom générique de la chose et son nom en même temps on dirait « Le paquebot France »; « Le France » est donc une abréviation. Dans le cas de « Bar Le France » il est tout à fait possible que « Le France » soit le nom du fameux paquebot auquel je réfère. Il est aussi possible que le nom raccourci soit réemployé et cela sera une construction toute personnelle des personnes qui possèdent le bar.

- un champagne (vin, région : La Champagne)
- le bourgogne  (vin, région : la Bourgogne)
- un roquefort (fromage fabriqué dans les environs de la ville de Roquefort)

**II**

Il est difficile de confirmer l'usage pour « un/une noisette »; on dit par exemple familièrement « c'est une nouille¹ » en parlant de quelqu'un, quel que soit le genre de la personne. De même on dit, quel que soit le genre, « une patate » (voir le TLFi), « un étourneau » (voir le TLFi).

Selon cette tendance il faudrait peut être dire « une noisette ». D'après le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/noisette) on doit dire « une noisette ».

¹<sub>Personne peu énergique et niaise</sub>

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse détaillée.

Comment: Une question supplémentaire: si le bar s’appelait « Bar la France », est-ce que ça semblerait normal aussi?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas C'est une autre possibilité tout à fait acceptable ; on trouve des *Bar Le français* (https://www.bing.com/search?q=Bar+Le+fran%C3%A7ais&form=PRFRFR&pc=UE00&httpsmsn=1&refig=5268b2c39e3e43dd8552569c64b47055&sp=-1&pq=bar+le+fran%C3%A7ais&sc=6-15&qs=n&sk=&cvid=5268b2c39e3e43dd8552569c64b47055) et même un *Bar la Française* https://www.bing.com/search?q=Bar+La+fran%C3%A7aise&form=PRFRFR&pc=UE00&httpsmsn=1&refig=402de7d2cf9d49d2aecb5af6be60649d&sp=-1&pq=bar+la+fran%C3%A7aise&sc=1-16&qs=n&sk=&cvid=402de7d2cf9d49d2aecb5af6be60649d, pourquoi pas « La France » ?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas On devrait même tolérer « *Bar de La France* » (Je n'en trouve pas), mais il existe des quantités de « *Bar de …* » : « *Bar de La Marine* », «  *Bar des Sports* »,  « *Bar des Pêcheurs* », « *Bars de [tel lieu]* », etc.