# Le genre de « Spa » (eau de Spa)

Tags: genre, noms-propres

Ma question porte sur l'eau de Spa. Si on commande un verre d'eau de Spa, dit-on : « garçon, un spa » ou « une spa » ?

Answer (score 1):

En dehors de Perrier, [le plus souvent masculin](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13532/pourquoi-dit-on-un-perrier-le-genre-de-la-marque/32109#32109), à ma connaissance toutes les marques et autres noms propres substantivés, que ce soit d'eau minérale ou de source, sont utilisés au féminin :

> Une Spa, Une Orezza, une Vittel, une Évian, une Saint-Yorre, une Cristalline, une Volvic, une Hépar, une Badoit, une Carola, etc.

On peut en dire autant des [bières](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19159/un-or-une-before-beer-names-in-french/19162#19162), sauf en Belgique où l'on peut rencontrer quelques exceptions plus ou moins locales : *un Orval, un Lambic, un Faro*.

C'est donc bien le genre du produit (une eau, une bière, une liqueur mais un vin, un champagne, un soda, un cocktail, etc.) qui donnera le genre final.

Comment: Pour [la bière](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19162/358).

Comment: A noter que un/uyne Orval est [un long débat](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orval_(marque_de_bi%C3%A8re)), et on ne parle même pas du pluriel...  Lambic et Faro sont effectivement plus souvent masculin, mais d'une manière générale personne ne vous tiendra vraiment rigueur d'utiliser le féminin comme raccourci de "une bière de type ou marque Orval/Lambic/Faro"

Comment: @LaurentS.Oui, c'est pour ça que j'ai écrit "plus ou moins locales". Ce n'est pas un usage exclusif.

Answer (score -1):

En Belgique, on boit de **la** [SPA](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spa_(eau_min%C3%A9rale)) ! :)

En France, les eaux peuvent être commandées "*au féminin*", "*masculin*", ou "*neutre*": de *la* Vittel, de *la* Volvic, ou on boit "du Perrier" (mais on entend également "de la Perrier"), ou de l'Evian...etc...

Normalement, on parle de *l'eau de [ **localisation** ]*. Il n'y aurait donc pas de genre fluctuant, puisque c'est **une** eau provenant d'**un** lieu/terroir; et néanmoins, si on veut utiliser seulement le lieu/terroir en tant que nom, les variations semblent être légion.

Personnellement, dans de nombreuses régions où je me suis déplacé, j'ai entendu des régionalismes, mais rien qui me laisse penser qu'il y ait une règle prédéfinie ou un genre à respecter.

Très souvent, le marketing et les publicités vont donner un axe de "*genre*", surtout à cause du leitmotiv qu'il veulent nous voir enregistrer et copier.

Comment: Hormis Perrier j'ai du mal à penser à une eau qui soit commandée au masculin en France, mais peut-être cela ne m'a-t-il jamais frappé lors d'aucun séjour...

Comment: J'ai entendu plein de fois "*un vittel*", et le serveur demander "nature ou sirop". Idem pour "*un Vichy*". Et ce sont uniquement ceux qui me viennent rapidement à l'esprit...

Comment: 2/2 Pourquoi "*un*" ? peut-être parce que les gens pensent "un quart vittel", et disent juste "un vittel". Ou "un verre de ....". En tous cas, c'est très courant où j'ai voyagé, c.a.d beaucoup d'endroits en France (sauf Bretagne où je ne suis jamais allé).

Comment: Je veux bien vous croire, vous semblez avoir plus d'expérience que moi en la matière, d'autant qu'en Belgique on fait rarement la distinction, on commande une au plate ou une eau pétillante et on découvre la marque quand la bouteille arrive :-)

Comment: En Belgique, je commande de la Spa ou de la Chaudfontaine, c'est vrai que la distinction ne m'a jamais frappée, au niveau du genre (pas du goût, bien sûr)